# Attempt to compare character in string to carriage return does not work

Tags: c++, string, carriage-return

I have some code to read a text based file format in that it checks for empty line with:

```
line == ""
```

where line is a string that receives a text line obtained through getline.

It worked with my own text based file format, but it did not work with another text based file format (not mine)

I opened the file with gedit and saw nothing. More and less utilities also did not show anything. Then I tried vi and it showed:

^M on all these lines that seemed empty until now (a screenshot of it is here: [image: Screenshot.png].

Did some research and it seems that opening the file in text mode, all I needed to do was to compare it to '\n'. So I wrote the line:

```
 if (line[0] == '^M' || line[0] == '\n') 
     break;
```

to end a while loop where this "if" is inside, but it did not work. What do I need to do?

Comment: `line[0] == '^M'` -- The compiler didn't give you a warning here?

Comment: `'^M'` is not valid; it's just your editor's way of displaying the control character. Try checking against `\r`. `\n` is a newline; `\r`is the carriage return.

Comment: `^M` is how your text editor displays the character - C++ doesn't understand that. And whether or not you will ever see the character depends on how you are reading the file, which you have not shown. Post some code.

Comment: *Then I tried vi and it showed:* -- Instead, you should get a binary editor to actually see the value that's there.

Comment: "carriage return" and "line feed" are anachronisms we are still stuck with. Sometimes the combo "\r\n" is referred to as CRLF. There are difference between OS's that derived from Unix where the CR is dropped and those from DOS which has separate CR's and LF's to end lines. So you see those differences when moving text files between OSs.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already surmised, those `^M`s are vi's way of showing you that there are carriage return characters at the end of each line.  The file probably originated on Windows.

As other commentators have mentioned, the way a carriage return character is represented in C / C++ is `'\r'`, and the line endings in that particular file will almost certainly actually be `\r\n` (CRLF).

So, now you know how it all works you have some code to write.  `getline` will remove the `\n` but you'll have to strip the `\r` (if there is one) off the end of the line yourself.  Go to it.